# How to refresh the UI in a metro app?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

I'm using this code in a XAML page:

```
<TextBox ItemsSource="{Binding Posters, Converter={StaticResource collectionToFirstElementConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Posters is an ObsevableCollection and I'm using a converter where takes the collection and gets the first element of it.

As I'm using async procedures, where the textbox receives the object, this one has no elements (Count=0), and calls the converter.

I'm trying to update the textbox everytime the property add new elements, but not calls the converter.

I remember that in Silverlight or WPF, exists SourceTrigger or UpdatePropertyChanged, but in WinRT I can't see this mode.

Comment: Why not just expose a property for the first element on your datacontext?

Comment: The problem is that I'm using async.. so when the textbox tries to load that property, it gets null! So I need a way to get the element tells the UI the refresh the property

Comment: Why not just fire the OnChanged event (I think that's the event name) when the async operations complete?

Comment: No, I don't find that event. In reality, I need some way to refresh or update UI since code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve that would be to modify your view model containing the `Posters` property accordingly. I can see two ways to go about it (both asuming that your view model implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`):

- Add an event handler to `Posters.CollectionChanged` and inside it raise `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged` for `Posters`.
- Add another property `FirstPoster` returning the value of the first element in `Posters`. In the view model add an event handler to `Posters.CollectionChanged` and inside it raise `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged` for `FirstPoster`. This way you don't even need the converter.

I personally like the second approach better.